# What would be the equivalent of the following code in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am working on a project and I was basing myself on one that had in windows forms the problem is that in WPF there is no DataGridView there is only DataGrid and that is generating problems when I want to select a row to be able to modify it

```
  private void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            Editar = true;
            txtNombre.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString();
            txtMarca.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Marca"].Value.ToString();
            txtDesc.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Descripcion"].Value.ToString();
            txtPrecio.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Precio"].Value.ToString();
            txtStock.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Stock"].Value.ToString();
            idProducto = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("seleccione una fila por favor");
    }
```

Comment: The ideal way would be to use the MVVM pattern (you create a class for your data type then you make it the dataContext for your view, then you bind properties in xaml). Providing you with the really équivalent wpf code would be a bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of this question is huge and a "proper" answer isn't really going to fit so this is necessarilly a lightning tour of the approach usually used.

In case you didn't quite "get it" wpf is different from winforms. The whole concept of MVVM will be completely foreign to someone used to winforms development.

You bind and data template rather than transferring data in code and pretty much every team uses MVVM. There are good reasons for this.

To get data into a wpf datagrid you'd usually bind it's itemssource to an observablecollection of row viewmodels. A viewmodel is "just" a class which implements inotifypropertychanged and has a public property per column ( or other property ).

It can also expose icommands. These are your "do stuff" equivalents to click event handlers.

Glossing over a few things lets say you have a StockLevelsView which is a window all about what stock of stuff you have. This has got a datagrid in it to show your data.
The datacontext of the window would be set to a StockLevelsViewModel. Amongst other things that could have a public property StockList which is an observablecollection of StockViewModel. A StockViewmodel would have public properties for Nombre, Marca etc. It's quite similar to the DTO or entity framework model you might have for the Stock table. It's in StockViewModel you would put dataattributes for validation and business logic. You get your date and copy each into a stockviewmodel. Maybe using automapper.

In this way you have a datagrid full of data.

A datagrid inherits from Selector https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netcore-3.1

As that suggests, you can select a row in the datagrid and this then becomes the selecteditem. You will want to set selectionmode to single for this.

Selecteditem is a dependency property which means you can bind it. So you can bind selecteditem to another public property in your StocksViewModel. In a side by side or overlaid panel you can then bind datacontext to that property. Or you could bind that datacontext directly to the selecteditem of the datagrid.

Either way your datacontext of a panel becomes that selected item which is a StockViewModel.  You can then bind properties of StockViewModel in that panel. Maybe all of them get a textbox and the text property of that is bound to that column.

The user edits and then you carry out validation using inotifydataerrorinfo before you persist.

An overview of markup:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding StocksList}"
              Name="StocksDG"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              />
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=StocksDG">
        <TextBlock Text="Nombre:"
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
            ....
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

You select a row on the left, the textboxes on the right are bound to that row's data so Nombre etc is editable.

Worth mentioning again that all viewmodels should always implement inotifypropertychanged.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

You will want to use a framework such as prism mvvm or mvvmlight. If for no other reason than delegatecommand or relaycommand which you'll want for icommand implementations.